# JavaScript - Logging just before a redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an ajax call (for logging purposes) just before I redirect. Actually, the redirect is a download that has octet-stream and disposition set up properly. So the ajax call does not gets called on all browsers (particularly chrome). In others like IE it does. How can I make sure the call gets executed for SURE?

this is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#download-link-a').click(function() {
        remoteLog ('Clicked on download', '<?php echo $username; ?>' );
        location.href = "<?php echo $secure_link; ?>";
        return false;
    });
});
function remoteLog (arg, key) {
    var file = '/files/remoteLog.php';
    $.post(file, {text: arg, key: key});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a callback function to invoke the redirect *only* after a successful `POST`. I suggest that you use `$.ajax()` instead of `$.post()` because it's  more customizable.

Here's how you can turn your `$.post()` into an `$.ajax()` equivalent with the appropriate callback functions:

```
$(function() {
    $('#download-link-a').click(function() {
        remoteLog ('Clicked on download', '<?php echo $username; ?>' );
        return false;
    });
});

function remoteLog (arg, key) {

    var fnSuccess = function() {
        location.href = "<?php echo $secure_link; ?>";
    };

    var fnFail = function() {
        alert('POST failed. Do not redirect!');
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/files/remoteLog.php',
      success: fnSuccess,
      error: fnFail,
      data: {text: arg, key: key},
      dataType: 'json',
      async:true
    });
}
```

More reading: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

Move the redirection to a callback function:

```
function remoteLog (arg, key) {
    var file = '/files/remoteLog.php';
    $.post(file, {text: arg, key: key})
      .always(function(){location.href = "<?php echo $secure_link; ?>";});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#download-link-a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        remoteLog ('Clicked on download', '<?php echo $username; ?>' );

    });
});
function remoteLog (arg, key) {
    var file = '/files/remoteLog.php';
    var jqPost = $.post(file, {text: arg, key: key})
    .always( function() { //or .done() can also be used
       location.href = "<?php echo $secure_link; ?>";
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a `onbeforeunload` and a synchrone ajax call.

```
$("#some-link").click(function(evt){
     this.outlink = $(this).attr("href");
     this.outtext = "Some text";
});

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  data = {text:this.outtext,outlink:this.outlink};
  $.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:"POST",
    data:data,
    async:false
  });
};
```

In fact, your only problem is the `async` part of your ajax call.